# Client/Server Programming for Allowing Multiple Clients

Tags: c, sockets, server, client

So currently I am trying to write a code where the client sends a code and a number to the server where the server will use that code to figure out which conversion it needs to make for the number. As of now I have the whole program written up but only for one client. How do I make it to where it accepts up to 10 clients?

```
/* convserver2.cc
 *
 * Created by: Aaron Eiser
 * 2/26/2020
 */

#include "socket.h"
#include "fdset.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

void ctrlCHandler(int signal);
float conversion(unsigned char code, float value);
bool isValid(unsigned char code);

const unsigned char CONV_CODES[] = {0, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32};
const int LENGTH = 19;
const int MAX_CLIENTS = 10;
int clientSock[10];
int master_socket, new_socket, activity, valread, sd, max_sd;
ServerSocket theServer;
Socket *theClient = NULL;

// struct for packet
struct Packet{
    float value;
    char gap[3];
    unsigned char code;
};



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fd_sett readfds;

    int port = atoi(argv[1]);

    for(i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENTS; i++){
        clientSock[i] = 0;
    }


    /* Bind the server listening socket to the given port. */
  theServer.bind(port);    
  printf("Server bound to port #%d\n", port);

  Packet data;

  bool flags = true;
  while(flags){
      signal(SIGINT, ctrlCHandler);

      theClient = theServer.accept();
      printf("Connection made\n");

      int size = theClient -> recv(&data, sizeof(Packet));
      printf("Packet receieved\n");

      while(size > 0 and data.code != 0){
          Packet newData;
          if(!isValid(data.code)){
              fprintf(stderr, "Invalid code\n");
              newData.code = 0;
              newData.value = conversion(data.code, data.value);
              theClient -> send(&newData, sizeof(Packet));
              printf("Packet sent\n");
              size = theClient -> recv(&data, sizeof(Packet));
              printf("Packet received\n");
          }
          else{
              newData.code = data.code;
              newData.value = conversion(data.code, data.value);
              theClient -> send(&newData, sizeof(Packet));
              printf("%d %f \n", newData.code, newData.value); 
              printf("Packet sent\n");
              size = theClient -> recv(&data, sizeof(Packet));
              printf("Packet received\n");
          }
      }
      theClient -> close();
      delete theClient;
  }
}

float conversion(unsigned char code, float value){
    float newValue;
    // Conv code 11
    if(code == 11){
        newValue = (value - 32) * (5.0 / 9.0);
        printf("something\n");
    }
    // Conv code 12
    else if(code == 12){
        newValue = (value - 32) * (5.0 / 9.0) + 273.15;
    }
    // Conv code 13
    else if(code == 13){
        newValue = (value * (9.0 / 5.0)) + 32;
    }
    // Conv code 14
    else if(code == 14){
        newValue = value + 273.15;
    }
    // Conv code 15
    else if(code == 15){
        newValue = (value - 273.15) * (9.0 / 5.0) + 32;
    }
    // Conv code 16
    else if(code == 16){
        newValue = value - 273.15;
    }
    // Conv code 21
    else if(code == 21){
        newValue = value / 12.0;
    }
    // Conv code 22
    else if(code == 22){
        newValue = value / 36.0;
    }
    // Conv code 23
    else if(code == 23){
        newValue = value / 63360.0;
    }
    // Conv code 24
    else if(code == 24){
        newValue = value * 12.0;
    }
    // Conv code 25
    else if(code == 25){
        newValue = value / 3.0;
    }
    // Conv code 26
    else if(code == 26){
        newValue = value / 5280.0;
    }
    // Conv code 27
    else if(code == 27){
        newValue = value * 36.0;
    }
    // Conv code 28
    else if(code == 28){
        newValue = value * 3.0;
    }
    // Conv code 29
    else if(code == 29){
        newValue = value / 1760.0;
    }
    // Conv code 30
    else if(code == 30){
        newValue = value * 63360.0;
    }
    // Conv code 31
    else if(code == 31){
        newValue = value * 5280.0;
    }
    // Conv code 32
    else if(code == 32){
        newValue = value * 1760.0;
    }
    return newValue;
}

// Decides whether code is valid
bool isValid(unsigned char code){
    for(int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++){
        if(code == CONV_CODES[i]){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Catches Ctrl C
void ctrlCHandler(int signal){
    if(theClient != NULL){
        theClient -> close();
    }
    theServer.close();
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: It looks as though each 'while loop' iteration accepts a new client, receives and handles a request before closing the connection.  So technically, your server can serve any number of new clients one after the other.  Did you mean processing up to 10 clients concurrently?

Comment: You also don't need to call signal(...) at each iteration.

Comment: This problem is frequently solved with multithreading; are you familiar with this concept? The details of how you implement this will likely depend on what system you are on (Windows vs Linux), though cross-platform libraries such as OpenMP exist.